# OpenCL - C - Mirror of a matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, opencl

I'm making a project where I need to mirror an image vertically. The image is read by a function and then set into an array pixel by pixel, to move through this array I am using `array[idy*w + idx]` (w being the width of the matrix or image in my case) now, since this will run concurrently I only need to find the opposite pixel so that I can assign it.

I mean something like this:

```
array[idy*w + idx] = array[opposite pixel];
array[opposite pixel] = array[idy*w + idx];
```

The problem is I can't find the proper way to do it.

Any answer would be highly appreciated.

I have tried doing the following but it doesn't work `array[idy*w + (w - (idx + 1))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
outputImage[idy*w + idx] = inputImage[idy*w + (w - idx - 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
pixel        = array[idy*w + idx];
pixel_mirror = array[idy * (w + 1) - idx - 1];
array[idy*w + idx] = pixel_mirror;
array[idy * (w + 1) - idx - 1] = pixel
```